# Clients of ejabberd XMPP server are receiving messages too slowly

Tags: performance, ejabberd

I have a ejabberd server and a few clients connected to it. They normally exchange messages and etc.

Clients are not the real people but the software.

It's all great when they just start working, but then they need to exchange with huge amounts of text data (for example 4K characters) and this is where problem is starting to appear. Each new message is sent to the server in ~10ms but receiving client gets it after ~10-40 seconds!

I tried to increase serversided limits (to 1 million) and it didn't help.

What can I do and what's the problem could be?

Comment: Then, even though big messages are sent out a lot of time ago, small messages for ~50 characters are taking the same amount of delivery time.

Comment: P.S. They all are connected to the same local network.